# What is the best way to implement consent page in spring?

Tags: spring, servlet-filters

We want to implement a consent page for customers visiting our website. One way I see is I can implement a filter which will check for a cookie, in case cookie is not present we will redirect the customer to /consent page. Once customer clicks on yes we will set a cookie. The filter will again check the cookies and customer can proceed with his requested pages.

Is there any out of box Interface provided by Spring which does this? I checked `OncePerRequestFilter` filter but it looks like it will not solve the requirement here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to Authentication through cookies. you can try about HandlerInterceptor.